# Floating Div without moving the other elements of the page

Tags: html, css

I want to insert a div into a page, put div into the coordinates that I want, but do not move the rest of the page content

What I had done is to put the parent container a **position: absolute** and the div that I want to have floating a **position: relative** and then go tell the px to position it where I want, but doing so the content of the page moves me Site, and I would like you not to move the rest of the content even if the div is above it.

What could I do ?

Comment: Post your code. But sounds like you need to reverse the position values. Use `relative` on the parent and `absolute` on the child.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of floating it, you'll need to position your div with either `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`.

Comment: and maybe torn your position absolute and relative around. make the container relative, end your floting div absolute

Answer (score 0):

You have to set **position: absolute** to the float div instead of the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with CSS. I would try setting the html tag to be relative and the div you want to absolute (if no other tags are set to relative).  Otherwise I would recommend jQuery for the solution.